# Placing a link inside of a tooltip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, tooltip

I have a situation where I need to display a link inside a tooltip.  I have found several posts where people state that the best way is a hidden div, but I cant find any examples of this being done.  Could anyone point me in the right place for an example of this?

Here is what I have so far for HTML.  I figure the rest of it will be done in Jquery, which is my weakness.

```
<td><%= f.check_box :raw_footage_check_finished, :checked => true %>
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none"><%= link_to 'Mark Incomplete', '#' %>
</div></td>
```

I am using Ruby on Rails for my server side language.

Comment: Is the problem with the link in the tooltip, or is the problem with displaying the tooltip itself? How are you calling the tooltip? Are you using a library? You'll need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Well originally I was calling it using the title property in the checkbox, but when I tried putting a Anchor tag in the title property it literally displayed '<a href='#'>Mark Incomplete</a>'.  I am using Jquery I am just not sure where to start with it

Comment: I can get the tooltip to show up just the link is not a link.  Its just text

Comment: Yeah you can't put html inside the title attribute, so you need to include another HTML element and style the tooltip yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use any jQuery unless you're doing something really fancy. You can use plain 'ol CSS like so:

```
.parent .tooltip {
    display: none;
}

.parent:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

It's not quite clear from your example how you want it to work, but here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DEtnP/

Also, try to avoid inline CSS wherever possible.

Comment: Thats it! Basically what it is, is a giant checklist of things to do.  So I want it when they check the activity complete they can not uncheck it unless they click the link in to tooltip just to make it a little harder